# Names of vectors in diffrent fragment and vertex shader files

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to make 2 objects in OpenGL with 2 diffrent textures and one of them should moving.

I make 2 shader program and sign it to diffrent indicates tabs. Parameters of shader programs looking but program draws only one obejct (which I use later). Is it correctly if I make .frag and .vert file same structure and name of in/out vectors but change only texture and delete transformation from static object?

```
//fragment of moving object
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;


out vec3 vecColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;


uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = projection*view* transform * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    vecColor = color;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
} 

// fragment of static object
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 vecColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection*view * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    vecColor = color;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
} 
// code of Use()
void Use() const
{
    glUseProgram(get_programID());
}

// Drawing elements in main event loop whiile()
// Draw first object
theProgram_stelaz.Use();
glBindVertexArray(VAO_stelaz);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _countof(indices_stelaz), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
// Draw second object
theProgram.Use();
glBindVertexArray(VAO_wings);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _countof(indices_wings), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Now program draws only secon object from indices_wings. I want to draw two elements and just object from indices_wings should move.

Comment: *"I make 2 shader program ..."* - Why is it not possible to draw both object with the same shader program? If the textures are different then it is sufficient to bind the proper texture before drawing the mesh. Note in one case the `transform` matrix can be set the identity matrix. It is very very expensive to change the shader program, but it is common to use a model (`transform`) matrix.

Comment: I should bind proper texture and change matrix transform to identity in while loop after drawind first object? (I will be grateful for any example how change it)

Comment: How are you signing the shader programs?

Comment: @genpfault , sign to indices tab? I create new VAO and sign like this             glBindVertexArray(VAO_stelaz);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _countof(indices_stelaz), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);